# Failed building wheel for PyAudio (M1 chip)

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

When I try to install PyAudio on my MAC (M1) with the command:

```
pip install PyAudio
```

I get the following error:

```
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.12.tar.gz (42 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Building wheel for PyAudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for PyAudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      running build_ext
      building '_portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DMACOSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/Users/dusankovacevic/Desktop/doctrina/venv/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src/_portaudiomodule.o
      src/_portaudiomodule.c:30:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include "Python.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyAudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I already have brew installed portaudio :/ and I am woring inside venv where I have pyenv install 3.9-dev installed
. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```html
try
sudo apt update
sudo apt install portaudio19-dev
pip install pyaudio
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).